# COM Interop Using Generic Types

Tags: c#, com, interop

It appears you can not use generic types directly with COM: see [Interoperating Using Generic Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229590%28VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Can anyone give an example of how this could be achieved?

Comment: Can you elaborate? You state it cannot be done then ask how it can be done. Do you have a specific scenario?

Comment: The referenced article says 'directlty' , so I assume there is some way to use them 'indirectly'.

The specific example is this one :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200576/find-all-controls-on-msform-from-c

Comment: Just to add some more information, VB.NET must do the 'indirect' something as the refrenced code works. If I  mispell the Controls collection, I get the error :

System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

So, I need to know what the missing something is, to get the code to run in c#!

Answer (score 4):

I think the idea is that you can't mark a generic type as `ComVisible` directly, but you can have that type implement non-generic interfaces that are `ComVisible`.

So, given a generic `Baker<Recipe>`, you would need to introduce something like:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IBake
{
   Pastry Bake();
}

public class Baker<Recipe> : IBake
{
   public Baker(Recipe ingredients) {...}

   public Pastry Bake()
   {
      ...
   }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Bakery
{
   public IBake GetBaker(string recipe)
   {
      // somehow get recipe type from string
      // and create and return Baker<Recipe>
      // Client can now call IBake.Bake().
   }
}
```

I suppose this is the "indirectly" that the article is talking about. I don't quite see what VB.NET's Controls collection has to do with this, however...

Comment: I think this is actually a bug (I don't know if it is with .net framework or COM Interop when using generic types.

To explain (using vb.net) :

If I allow VB.NET to work out what type of object the 'generic' designer object it, it correctly works out it is a userform (I know this by returning the type :Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName). If I expicitly set the generic object as a Userform, I get an error (in any .NET language) :
 {"The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105
(RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"}