# How to handle events from embedded Excel.OleObjects or Excel.Shapes

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba, vsto

I'm working on `C#` and now `VB.NET` ports of an old `VBA` program.  It has lots of `MSForms/OleObjects` embedded in it like `CommandButton` or even images.

My first thought was to declare all the buttons as `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton`but that leads to a `COM` exception that the `System._COM type` can't be cast to `...Forms.CommandButton`.  If I try a more generic version of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200576/find-all-controls-on-msform-from-c-sharp), I don't find any items, and if I try to go through all `VBComponet`s I note that they are all the sheets in the `workbook`, but none of the controls:

```
foreach (VBComponent xxx in Globals.ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents) {
    Interaction.MsgBox(xxx.Name);
    Interaction.MsgBox(xxx.ToString);
}
```

Thus all of these controls are not in `.VBComponets`, but I can find them as **OLEobjects** in `thisworkbook.worksheets(n).OLEobjects` (this is counterintutive to me, but I probably don't understand the system to begin with).

**How do I handle the Click action from such an object?**

I'm assuming that I need to be using the `Excel.OLEObjectEvents_Event` interface, but I can't seem to figure out how.  If I try to make custom events with `delegates`, I don't seem to be able to assign them to `OleObjects`.  If I use `ActionClickEventHandler.CreateDelegate` I can get a huge variety of errors that makes me think that's a dead end.

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.oleobject(v=office.15).aspx) from MS doesn't seem that helpful, though it did introduce me to the [idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._oleobject_members(v=office.15).aspx) of `Verb`, which I'm looking into.  So far that has only produced COM errors along the lines of "Application Failed to start."

Even just trying to use one of the two standard events, `.GotFocus`, I always pull a 0x80040200 error.
Example:

```
Excel.OLEObject ButtonCatcher = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("CommandButton1");
ButtonCatcher.GotFocus += CommandButton1_Click;
```

Throws a COMException `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040200` at the second line.  The button is enabled, which is I checked after looking up the [code number from the office dev site.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dd757489(v=vs.100).aspx)

Trying a more [generic approach](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/fr-FR/dee3ba0a-cc7c-4e9b-b469-ffbd42ea7295/invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-systemcomobject-to-interface-type?forum=vsto) within the code for a sheet containing controls:

```
object CommandButtonStart = this.GetType().InvokeMember("CommandButton1", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, this, null);
```

> Throws a Missing Method error.

Any help is greatly appreciated, this seems like this should be obvious and I'm missing it.

---

**Edit:  I have also found that I can cast these controls into `Excel.Shape` but that doesn't actually get me any closer to running a function or sub from the VSTO.  I'm playing with `Excel.Shape.OnAction` but this requires a VBA sub to be called.  Presumably, I could call a VBA sub which calls a sub from the VSTO as long as the VSTO was COM visible.  This seems really round-about and I'd only like to do it as a last resort.

Comment: Have you established whether they are ActiveX controls on the worksheet? Regular forms controls (non activeX) don't exhibit events and can only call subs through the onAction method. Which is possibly where you're running into issues?

Comment: Help my ignorance.  I find VBA embedded in an Office software program (or one of the other programs that has adopted it).  VBA is not stand-alone.  So what is `an old VBA program`?

Comment: Just an aside, but according to my travel agent, all the good "last resorts" are "really round-about".  It's almost a rule.

Comment: @Kyle They are ActiveX controls, and can, for instance, be made to disappear by disabling ActiveX through TructCenter options.

Comment: @Smandoli Certainly true that it is not a complete program, but programming taxonomy is not my strong suit (hit me at Bio.SE for help with actual taxonomy). Should we borrow from VSTO and call the project an add-in? I don't mind anyone editing that phrase to be more correct. I didn't code the original, and was never too found of VBA. A VBA solution? Organized collection of macros?  I think the point comes across, no?

Comment: In Excel, you could call non-private Subs on other workbooks by `Application.Run "SubNameFromOtherWorkbook"`. But those on the Sheet buttons/checkboxes/etc are meant to interact with VBA. Are you trying to log the user actions on them?

Comment: @PatricK I was aiming to be able expose the actions to .Net so I could handle the actions in a VSTO.  The button/form layout is so extensive that I was hoping to not make one of my students replicate it.  I was trying to move from a VBA solution to a VSTO solution, and was updating and tweaking many of the Subs. Thus, my goal is to not have to rebuild the Excel sheets as well.

Comment: Why are you porting it? VBA is still supported. Code doesn't rust...

Comment: @Ben The VBA code is old, and crosses several breakable changes when run in MS Office 2010 or 2013.  Rather than continue the project in VBA, I hoped to move to .Net solution so that we could build a much richer add-in (or at least more easily, I had hoped).  More of our lab has experience in C# than anything else, so it seemed the obvious choice if we were going to modernize the project.

Comment: This sort of error generally means the type library is not registered. The actual error 0x80040200 is SELFREG_E_TYPELIB which means the object has attempted to register its own type library and failed. Probably this is because it requires elevated privileges to do so. You need to use regsvr32.exe or Regtlb.exe to register it. (I.e. locate the dll, then run regsvr32.exe "c:\path\to\control.dll").

Comment: Brilliant question, have been looking around for a few hours now but I am giving up...

Comment: @Ben Interesting point.  For deployment we'd have to hand that within the installer, but I'm trying it now on my Dev machine.  If I can get it to work, I'll suggest that you turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Ben Coming back to this, just for the sake of posterity, registering and elevating with regsvr32.exe did not work, though we left it in so that the VSTO continues with elevated privileges (it's on an air gapped network).  I ended up making grad students remake the entire project from scratch in C#, as we couldn't overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution Type:** [VSTO Document-Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386206.aspx)

**Scenario:**
1.) Excel.Worksheet created at run-time. (not a [Worksheet Host Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc6dt58x.aspx))
2.) Add a button on the Worksheet at run-time that triggers C# code when clicked.

**Assembly References:** 
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop  (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll)
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.dll)
Microsoft.VisualBasic  (Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

**Tested / Working Code:**

```
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton CmdBtn;

private void CreateOLEButton()
{
   Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets["MyWorksheet"];

   // insert button shape
   Excel.Shape cmdButton = ws.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.CommandButton.1", Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 500, 5, 100, 60);
   cmdButton.Name = "btnButton";

   // bind it and wire it up
   CmdBtn = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton)Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(ws, null, "btnButton", new object[0], null, null, null);
   CmdBtn.Caption = "Click me!";
   CmdBtn.Click += new MSForms.CommandButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(ExecuteCmd_Click);
}

private void ExecuteCmd_Click()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Click");
}
```

Comment: This works, but the click event disappears after a while. You can click a few times and then the button stops working. Any idea of what could be happening? All methods I tried do the same thing.

Comment: @DanielMöller I didn't experience that behavior. It sounds like you've done some sleuthing though. COM+ can be very tricky and I'm not a COM expert to be able to chime in here. Please post if you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I found out that the garbage collector was killing my objects. I had to declare them outside the method as static members so they keep in memory after the method runs. Now, unfortunately my events only keep alive while the source application is running, they don't persist in the sheet

Comment: Garbage collector! huh, it doesn't play nice with COM+ objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using NewLateBinding.LateGet?

```
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

...

MSForms.CommandButton CommandButton1 = (MSForms.CommandButton)NewLateBinding.LateGet(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1), null, "CommandButton1", new object[0], null, null, null);                
CommandButton1.Click += new Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(CommandButton1_Click);
```

It's referenced on MSDN in the [VSTO forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb59c668-9939-4171-aea4-7b750e31f13d/c-excel-plugin-commandbutton-click-event-only-fires-once?forum=vsto) and in an [old blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/10/02/excel-how-to-run-c-code-behind-with-a-click-of-a-button-on-a-worksheet-without-vba-code.aspx).

Comment: Nope I'll give that a try.

Comment: Still getting 0x80040200, combined with Ben's comment, we might be able to get it to work.

Comment: Even with elevated registered library, still got the `0x80040200` error.  Seemed like a good idea though.  Found this wasn't hard to test, make an ActiveX button and try NewLateBinding.LateGet to throw the error at that line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you programmatically add code to a CodeModule in the Workbook, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994235/handling-events-for-oleobject-commandbuttons-created-at-runtime)?

```
Private Sub CommonButton_Click(ByVal buttonName As String)
  MsgBox "You clicked button [" & buttonName & "]"
End Sub

Private Sub CreateEventHandler(ByVal buttonName As String)
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim codeText As String
    Dim LineNum As Long

    Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Me.CodeName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    LineNum = CodeMod.CountOfLines + 1

    codeText = codeText & "Private Sub " & buttonName & "_Click()" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  Dim buttonName As String" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  buttonName = """ & buttonName & "" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  CommonButton_Click buttonName" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "End Sub"
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, codeText
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried it and threw Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040200, let me play with this a min

Comment: Trying to clean this up a little, few invalid casts as well.  Ie Me.Codename is Sheet1 but needs to be int; so changing to this.index, etc.  Got it to compile, but it doesn't add any function to the button.

Comment: If it was supposed to put the VBA macro at the end in one of the mods or sheet codes, it doesn't seem to have put them there (I checked all of them).  Button does nothing, I tried playing with the index cased to VBComp, but still nothing.

Comment: Ah, I just realized you meant this to be a VBA solution.  Yes I could call that to make the actions handled by VBA, but that is not at all related to my goal.  I'm trying to get them handled by a VSTO, not in VBA if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the interop forms toolkit. It is free from Microsoft. It provides com wrappers and event messenger class that communicates the event data to and from .NET to VBA. I have used it to handle control events from VBA in .NET, and events from .NET to VBA. You would use the interop

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15690/VB-C-Interop-Form-Toolkit.

From the toolkit ducoumentation:

Interop UserControls provide a basic set of intrinsic events (Click, GotFocus, Validate, etc.) in Visual Basic 6.0. You can define your own custom events in Visual Studio .NET and raise them using RaiseEvent. In order to handle the events in Visual Basic 6.0, you need to add a project reference and add a WithEvents variable declaration in your code, and then handle the events using the WithEvents variable rather than the control itself.

How To Handle Interop UserControl Custom Events

1.
In Visual Basic 6.0, on the Project menu, click References. Note that there is already a reference to ControlNameCtl, where ControlName is the name of your Interop UserControl.

2.
In the Available References list, locate a reference for ControlName and check it, and then click OK.

3.
In the Code Editor, add a declaration for a WithEvents variable:

```
Dim WithEvents ControlNameEvents As ControlLibrary.ControlName
```

In the Form_Load event handler, add the following code to initialize the WithEvents variable:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set ControlNameEvents = Me.ControlNameOnVB6Form
End Sub
```

Add code to handle your custom event in the WithEvents variable's event handler:

```
Private Sub ControlNameEvents_MyCustomEvent()
    MsgBox("My custom event fired")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Leo Gurdian 
In VB.Net look like this:

Assembly References:
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll)
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.dll)
Microsoft.VisualBasic (Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms

Private Sub CreateOLEButton()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = (CType(Application.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet))
    Dim cmdButton As Excel.Shape = ws.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.CommandButton.1", Type.Missing, False, False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 500, 5, 100, 60)
    cmdButton.Name = "btnButton"
    Dim CmdBtn As Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton = CType(Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(ws, Nothing, "btnButton", New Object(-1) {}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton)
    CmdBtn.Caption = "Click me!"
    AddHandler CmdBtn.Click, AddressOf ExecuteCmd_Click
End Sub
Private Sub ExecuteCmd_Click()
    'do something 
End Sub
```

Comment: From which namespace is this `AddHandler`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement